# how to link my SQL database with server globally

Tags: sql, asp.net, database

I have designed and developed a web application with asp.net and SQL server management. The project is working fine in my computer. But I need to host(deployed) this project in servers. Problem which I faced: the connection string and the URL which I have used is linked to my computer. So how can I step ahead and move on with this project.

I need to host my dynamic website which is running fine. I need to know how to use connection string.

```
con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString);
    cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
```

Comment: Where is the website and db deployed? On the same server or different servers?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to store your connection string in your web.config file.  Then, when you deploy your asp.net application, you can deploy your "production" version of your web.config which will contain all your production-specific information, including your connection string.

Check out [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) about connection strings and web.config for more detailed information.